# vis.js timeline how to check if there is currently an appointment

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, frontend, vis.js

Is there an event or something similar that triggers when an item starts ?

[image: Vis.js timeline]

Well, basically what I want is an event (or something else that works) that will trigger when the red line crosses, in this example, 10:00am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to close this question.
There sadly is no API for this, but a simple timeout will do.

```
setTimeout(function () {
   //do stuff on appointment begin
   setTimeout(function () {
       //do something when finished
   }, end - Date.now());
}, start - now);
```

Ps. you'll have to do this for each appointment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the red line is just the current time. You can have a time interval fired each, let's say, 3 seconds and check if you have any item of the timeline crossing the line. Like this pseudocode:

```
var timeline = ... // This is the timeline object

setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date(); // This is the current position of the timeline
    for (var d in timeline.itemsData._data) {
         if (d.start <= now && d.end >= now) { // this means the red line is crossing this item
             // do something...
         }
    }
}, 3); // each 3 seconds
```

The code is not complete. But there's the main idea.

Comment: I would not suggest doing this

Comment: That simply is not true. If you know how to do it, it causes no harm. Here some good read about it: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling